# Trying to return fetch's response array ends up with undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, response, fetch

There's my code:

```
   fetch(data)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(newData => array.push(newData))
let be = array[0].id;
```

I'd like to access my array data, but I end up with undefined and I don't know why.
[After reloading page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFy3d.png)
However it works just fine in console.
[Working good with console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2l96.png)
I've been reading all over the internet for hours, but I can't seem to understand why does it work like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` run asynchronously so, you can do something like this.

```
let array = [];
let be = '';

fetch(data)
 .then(blob => blob.json())
 .then(newData => {
    array.push(newData);
    be = array[0].id;
 });
```

As soon as you call your fetch method, while it wait's response from the server or from wherever you are trying to get the information, the i/o doesn't stop and starts executing the rest of the code while waiting the response from server.

Comment: It does work indeed, thank you. (I'd upvote but i'm noob in terms of overstack and don't know how to do it )